# Pandas dataframe compare all column values of index without column-name reference

Tags: python, pandas

I have an indexed dataframe that contains many columns, some examples:

```
    Feature1
    Feature2
    Feature3
    Feature4
....
```

What i simply want to implement a function, to create a new dataframe(or another data-structure type) object which will compare values of one test-sample row values with all other rows(test sample included), if values are equal; comparison result will be "1" else "0", but as i have 91 columns, i don't want to give reference to column names, i've seen many examples that column names are given to some pandas functions.

Data example for classified_data object(NaN means `null`)

```
_product Feature1 Feature2 Feature3 Feature4
SRI3012  1        yes         IN    NaN
SRI3015  1        yes         IN    NaN
SRS3012  1        no          OUT   Val1
```

I've simply tried :

```
##Choose sample
    test_sample = classified_data.sample();
#Find index of random sample
    test_product_code = list(test_sample.index.values)[0]
##Find location of random product in data-set
    test_index = classified_data.index.get_loc(test_product_code)
    #print(test_sample);
    #print(classified_data[(test_index):(test_index+1)])
    enum_similarity_data = pandas.DataFrame(calculate_similarity_for_categorical(classified_data[(test_index):(test_index+1)],classified_data).T,index=classified_data.index)


def calculate_similarity_for_categorical(value1,value2):
    if(value1 == value2):
        return 1;
    else:
        return 0;
```

Desired output for SRI3012(assumption to be choosen randomly) a dataframe or another object having column names and values:

```
_product Feature1 Feature2 Feature3 Feature4
SRI3012  1        1        1        1
SRI3015  1        1        1        1
SRS3012  1        0        0        0
```

Comment: I always try not to downvote those questions with data screenshots...

Comment: You are right, sorry for inconvnience, question is edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `DataFrame.eq`

You can check equality of one row with all other rows specifying `axis=1`. **The comparison here should be `DataFrame.eq(Series, axis=1)`** If you consider `NaN == NaN` to be `True` (which is not the standard) we need to deal with that separately.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', np.NaN], ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', np.NaN], 
                   ['A', 'X', 'Z', 'C', np.NaN], [6, 'foo', 'bar', 12, 1231.1]])
#   0    1    2   3       4
#0  A    A    B   C     NaN
#1  A    A    B   C     NaN
#2  A    X    Z   C     NaN
#3  6  foo  bar  12  1231.1

s = df.iloc[0]  # or df.iloc[np.random.choice(range(df.shape[0]))]
(df.eq(s, axis=1) | (s.isnull() & df.isnull())).astype(int)
                     # so NaN == NaN is True

#   0  1  2  3  4
#0  1  1  1  1  1
#1  1  1  1  1  1
#2  1  0  0  1  1
#3  0  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: It returns exception in a way that "cannot convert float NaN to integer", i've changed last part to -> "astype(float)", now exception is gone but output dataframe contains "nan"s, no "0" or "1"s...

Comment: I've directly used same implementation you are given, it directly creates exception. When i've changed to astype(float), only same row contains 1's all other values in new dataframe is "nan"s... When i've removed the part " | (s.isnull() & df.isnull())", again same row contains "1"s all others are full of "0"s. Maybe it is a topic that i am selecting my row with sample() function of dataframe ?

Comment: @Hayra yes. `sample` returns an object with the same type as the caller. So your `s` is a DataFrame, mine is a Series. You don't want a `DataFrame` because that forces alignment on both axes while you only care about the columns alignment. If you want select the row randomly with `df.iloc[np.random.choice(range(df.shape[0]))]`, sample uses that internally anyway

Comment: Thanks for fast answer, but on dataframe i am using index to identify row, within that i will lose index most probably ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i've handled index part by dropping index then re-adding it again after i calculated comparison matrix, maybe there were more operations but it worked.

Comment: forgot to accept that answer, sorry for this delay :)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment, so I 'll comment here. As Quang Hoang commented, you should not use screanshots but simple and nicely-formated data that anyone who spends their precious time to help you, can copy. Also, all this complex information is not necessary. You can reproduce the notion of your question with a simple dummy DataFrame with simple values and names. This way you will get better and faster answers.

Try this:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'Feature1':[    1 ,     1 ,    1 ],
                   'Feature2':[ 'yes',  'yes',  'no'], 
                   'Feature3':[ 'IN' ,  'IN' , 'OUT'],
                   'Feature4':[np.NaN, np.NaN,    5 ]
                  },
                  index=['SR12', 'SR13', 'SR14']
)
df.index.name = '_product'

def compare_against_series(x, reference):
    """compares a Series against a reference Series"""
    # apply .astype(int) to convert boolean to 0-1
    return np.logical_or(x == sample, x.isnull() & sample.isnull()).astype(int)

# take the 1st row as sample 
sample = df.iloc[0]

# apply compare_against_series row-wise, using the sample
# note axis=1 means row-wise and axis=0 column-wise
result = df.apply(compare_against_series, axis=1, reference=sample)
```

df:

```
          Feature1 Feature2 Feature3 Feature4
_product                            
SR12             1      yes       IN      NaN
SR13             1      yes       IN      NaN
SR14             1       no      OUT      5.0
```

sample:

```
Feature1      1
Feature2    yes
Feature3     IN
Feaure4     NaN
Name: SR12, dtype: object
```

result:

```
          Feature1  Feature2  Feature3  Feautre4
_product                              
SR12             1         1         1         1
SR13             1         1         1         1
SR14             1         0         0         0
```

Comment: You are right, sorry for inconvnience, question is edited.